# XSL Transformation using templates in sequence

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

How can I transform XML using two templates in sequence?
For example, I've one XML that has *string XML* in it, so I need to trasform this *string XML* into XML and after that I need to remove **invoices** node.

**input.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MT_STATEMENT_response >
  <Statement_response>
    <P_INVOICE>
        &lt;invoices&gt;
          &lt;invoice&gt;
             &lt;number&gt;12345&lt;/number&gt;
             &lt;status/&gt;
          &lt;/invoice&gt;
          &lt;invoice&gt;
             &lt;number&gt;67890&lt;/number&gt;
             &lt;status/&gt;
          &lt;/invoice&gt;
       &lt;/invoices&gt;
    </P_INVOICE>
  </Statement_response>
</MT_STATEMENT_response>
```

**transformer.xsl**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="ext">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:variable name="t1">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Statement_response" />
      </xsl:variable>

      <xsl:apply-templates mode="pass2" select="ext:node-set($t1)/*" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Statement_response">
    <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="invoices" mode="pass2">
    <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Expected**

```
<invoice>
  <number>12345</number>
  <status/>
</invoice>
<invoice>
  <number>67890</number>
  <status/>
</invoice>
```

Comment: If you use XSLT 3.0 with e.g. Saxon 9.8 (all editions) or Altova 2017 or 2018 you can use `parse-xml` to parse the contents and then if needed a mode to transform it. With disable-output-escaping you would need to use two separate stylesheets as it is a serialization step which doesn't work with variables, temporary trees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using XSLT 3 and the `parse-xml` function (https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-parse-xml) you could output those `invoice` elements escaped in the original input in the `P_INVOICE` element using

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy-of select="parse-xml(//P_INVOICE)//invoice"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I'm using XSLT inside SAP PI and version 3 doesn't work at all. I don't know even version 2 works properly. Thank you @martin!

Comment: I don't know anything about XSLT support inside SAP PI, you could check with https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt/processorTest3.xml what it outputs about `xsl:version` and `xsl:product-name`/`xsl:product-version` to see which underlying XSLT processor it uses and then check its documentation whether it has an extension function similar to the `parse-xml` introduced in XPath 3. Otherwise you will have to chain two transformations, one that uses `disable-output-escaping`, the second to strip that `invoices` element.

Comment: I followed your suggestion and I used two transformations chained. By the way, I'll mark your answer as correct because it solves the question. Thank you!